# For as expression

Tags: python

The `for` operator can also be used as an expression, like in

```
print(c for c in iter)
```

The python language reference makes no mention of this, or at least I could not find it.

Is the value of this expression well defined, and is the a point of using it?

EDIT: I wrote this from the smartphone, but now that I'm back to the code I saw this in, I noticed an error as pointed out in the comments - I added the `c` in front of `for`.

Comment: What version of python are you using where that's not a SyntaxError?

Comment: The way you show it here it should give a Syntrax Error. But in Combination with a string, it works. By giving the `print` statement a String and binding it to the `for` loop as a condition, like @milanbalazs has shown further down in his answer

Comment: @milanbalazs shows an example of a generator expression which is totally legal. the OP's post however is not.

Comment: I have edited the question, I forgot to put down the "c" before "for" when typing it up on the smartphone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form of `for` loop is called a *generator* object, from [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

> Generator functions allow you to declare a function that behaves like
>   an iterator, i.e. it can be used in a for loop.

Also

> Generator expressions provide an additional shortcut to build
>   generators out of expressions similar to that of list comprehensions.
>
> In fact, we can turn a list comprehension into a generator expression
>   by replacing the square brackets ("[ ]") with parentheses.
>   Alternately, we can think of list comprehensions as generator
>   expressions wrapped in a list constructor.

example:

```
>>> (x for x in range(10))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000014DEA749E08>
```

Comment: Thank you! That nicely explains it. In the particular code I saw, the right hand side already was an iterator, i.e. `(c for c in iter)` - where the variable `iter` is an iterator already. Do I assume correctly that this whole expression then is a "nop", i.e., basically just wraps the original `iter` in an additional layer of iterator "sugar", in effect doing nothing at all?

Comment: yes it is generator built upon other generator, that does not do any pre/post processing, so yes you can assume that.

Comment: Might want to take that into your answer to round it up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the starting `*` character to print the all values of an iterator.

**Code:**

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(*my_list, sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
1
2
3
4
5
```

Or you can make more complex expressions with `*` character and list comprehension.

**Code:**

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(*[x for x in my_list if x > 2], sep="\n")
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
3
4
5
```

**NOTE:**

You can print the generator object as well, like this:

**Code:**

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(x for x in my_list)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py 
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f614ded7d58>
```

Comment: These examples are different from the the one in the question.

Comment: Why? The example code in the question contains SyntaxError (It is not possible to print a simple `for` loop in the print function). The questioner want to print an iterator and I have shown several possibilities for it.

Comment: Thank you for listing these options. I indeed do not want to print an iterator, but stumbled about the usage of `for` as an expression - I learned that this can be used to create an iterator -- and the usage of `print` for that in the original code was just nonsense, as it prints the representation of the iterator object, as in your last example.